# An unhandled exception occurred in the application . Additional information: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'

Tags: winforms

> An unhandled exception occurred in the application . Additional information: 
>   Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'. in winform application

NET 4.6 was installed on our build server and also installed in the application server .net frame work 4.6.1 sdk, but still issue is arise.

Comment: Where's the code? StackTrace?...

Comment: Did you reboot? I had to reboot the machine to get it working